# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context - entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am making a test blog application using enitity framework, and ran into this error:

> "Unable to create a constant value of type 'TestBlog.Models.Tag'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

I am using asp.net MVC with viewmodels passing data between my view and controller.

In my controller of ActionResult Edit posts, I have this statement:

```
return View("Form", new PostsForm
    {

        Tags = TestBlog.Tags.Select(tag => new TagCheckBox
        {
            Id = tag.Id,
            Name = tag.Name,
            IsChecked = post.Tags.Contains(tag)
        }).ToList() 
    });
```

I have also tried this version:

```
return View("Form", new PostsForm
    {
        Tags = (from item in TestBlog.Tags
                select item).Select(tag => new TagCheckBox
                {
                    Id = tag.Id,
                    Name = tag.Name,
                    IsChecked = post.Tags.Contains(tag)
                }).ToList()
    });
```

The issue seems to be caused by:

> IsChecked = post.Tags.Contains(tag)

as I comment that statement, it no longer displays the error.

Here is my Tag.cs Model

```
public class Tag
{
    public Tag()
    {
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my viewmodels:

```
public class TagCheckBox
{
    public int? Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set;}
}

public class PostsForm
{
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
    public int? PostId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(128)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(128)]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public IList<TagCheckBox> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
IsChecked = post.Tags.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(tag.Id)
```

**Update**

But actually, with navigation properties property set, you should be able to call:

```
Tags = post.Tags.Select(x => new TagCheckBox { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, IsChecked = x.IsChecked }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however I am not too familiar with lambdas.

What does "x => new TagCheckBox { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, IsChecked = x.IsChecked })" refer to?  

Visual Studio marks IsCheck = x.IsChecked as an error, since my Tag.cs class does not contain a definition for "IsChecked"

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

EF doesn't know your class TagCheckBox and cannot create an instance of it in SQL. Try it like this.

(Cannot set the formatting from my phone, apologies).

```
return View("Form", new PostsForm
    {
        Tags = (from item in TestBlog.Tags
                select item).Select(tag => new
                {
                    Id = tag.Id,
                    Name = tag.Name,
                    IsChecked = post.Tags.Any(t => t.Id == tag.Id)
                }).
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(tag => new TagCheckBox
                {
                    Id = tag.Id,
                    Name = tag.Name,
                    IsChecked = tag.IsChecked
                })
                .ToList()
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I was testing it, however I still receive the error: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'TestBlog.Models.Tag'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

However, it now displays error on: 
Line 65:   return View("Form", new PostsForm